# What does `$ClassInitFlag` do exactly?

Tags: delphi, class-constructors

When invoking code completion I saw the following:

[image]

The definition of `TSlice` looks like this.

```
  TSlice = record
  private
    class var RandomSeed: uint64;
    class constructor InitRandomSeed;
  public
   .....
  TSliceHelper = record helper for TSlice
  private
    class var BitMask: array[0..8] of TSlice;
    class constructor Init;
  end;
```

I'm assuming that `$ClassInitFlag` tells the runtime whether the class constructor has run or not, but there seems to be no documentation on this var. and the `$` is not in `['_', 'a'..'z','A'..'Z']`, so this is not a valid identifier and I cannot access this member in code.

What exactly does the runtime do with this flag, and is there some way to manipulate it?

Comment: They are inaccessible, [except through some hacking with offsets](https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-utils/issues/184#issuecomment-223033344). I bumped into [these release notes](http://www.devjetsoftware.com/products/codeinsightplus/) from Code Insight Plus, which describes an improvement, that those fields are now hidden, since they are inaccessible anyway. [Embarcadero describes a similar bugfix for D2010](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/40204). All in all, it looks like it's an error that you even see them, and the intention is that they are hidden, undocumented, and to be left alone.

Comment: @GolezTrol, in that case this is a regression that should be fixed.

Comment: Looks like it..